# Windows Task Scheduler is running my .exe multiple times

Tags: c#, taskscheduler

I have scheduled a Windows task using this command:

```
SchTasks /Create /SC MINUTE /mo 1 /TN PWSchedule /TR "C:\Program Files\Implant Sciences\B220\patches\batch\SanminaTaskSchedular.exe" /F
```

This is a batch file which creates a task and runs an .exe file.

The .exe file is a C# Windows Form Application which changes stuff in the database.

My problem is that I see multiple instances of Task Scheduler running in the taskbar/process. Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: You schedule the task to be started every minute - If it doesn't end within the current minute, another instance might be running in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

`/SC MINUTE` means the task will be scheduled by every minute. If you want your task to be scheduled only once, you should use `/SC ONCE`.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I want the window to run my task every minute but should not start multiples processes in the taskbar. Otherwise there will be 1000 task running by the end of the day

Comment: @rash The task scheduler will execute your program every minute. If your program does not close by itself, it will stay open and you will have thousands by the end of the day. Maybe you need to describe what you *want* to happen.

Comment: @nvoigt Agree. @rash To avoid `X-Y` question, you should tell us what you're really going to do or what kind of problem you're struggling with.

Comment: Alright I figured out the problem. It was my mistake. I created multiple task with same name several times from command line.

Comment: Thanks all who invested there time in figuring out the solution.

Comment: Does any one know how to run a winform app (.exe) file as windows taskSchedler.